# What happens if multiple scripts set window.onload?

Tags: javascript, onload

There are a number of posts on StackOverflow and other websites regarding the problem of avoiding namespace collisions. In my scenario, I just want a method in my JavaScript to be executed after the DOM is accessible.

If I do the following will it avoid namespace collisions?

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function() { //Define my namespace var here, and execute all my code }</script>
```

What if a script that is injected later also sets an onload function ? Will mine get overwritten? I'm fully aware that I can test this out, but I would also like some feedback as I am new to JavaScript and there could be a number of other scenarios which will do the something that I am not aware of.

EDIT: I need to support only Safari 5.0+

Comment: @Oriol is right. 
Since you are new to this... make your live easy... use JQuery. Don't get me wrong... learn JavaScript but learn it with JQuery

Comment: Off-topic: be aware that if you only want to wait until the DOM is ready, you should listen to `DOMContentLoaded` instead of `load`, which waits until images are loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the last one will overwrite the previous ones.

The solution: use the new event API: [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: addEventListener will not work with IE. As already suggested, unless there is some special reason for not using jQuery, use jQuery $(window).on("load", function() {});

Comment: @MaksymKozlenko Will not work only on old versions of IE, which nowadays have a very low usage. And you think everybody should use jQuery, but other people (like me) prefer other frameworks, such as the amazingly fast [vanilla-js](http://vanilla-js.com/).

Comment: Writing code in Assembly language is also faster, but most of us are using high level languages like C++ or JavaScript. Pure JS is nice for simple things, but when your application grows you need to use some frameworks to make your code modular. Unfortunately old IE 7 and 8 are still an issue since some companies IT departments are too lazy to upgrade Windows or use other more standards compliant browsers :-(

Answer (score 1):

This is a fine Javascript way to do it right

```
function addLoadEvent(func) {
 var oldonload = window.onload;
 if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
 } else {
    window.onload = function() {
    if (oldonload) {
      oldonload();
    }
    func();
   }
 }
}
addLoadEvent(nameOfSomeFunctionToRunOnPageLoad);
addLoadEvent(function() {
   /* more code to run on page load */
});
```

[Explained Source](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571)

Comment: The problem is that if asker doesn't have control over a script, it won't use this code and will rewrite his event listener.

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of information on this, but here's the short version:

if you want to play nicely with onload, you can do

```
var prev_onLoad = window.onload;
window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof(prev_onLoad)=='function')
        prev_onLoad();

    // rest of your onLoad handler goes here
}
```

and hope that other's play nicely or make sure that's the last setting of onload in the code.

However, more modern browsers have event registration functions (addEventListener and attachEvent on IE) which take care of this chaining among other things. Quite a few cross-browser onload event functions have been written which take care of this logic for you.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be overriden .
In Javascript, when you define handle event like

```
window.onload = function(){
   console.log("in Load function 1");

};
window.onload = function(){
  console.log(" In load function 2");
};
```

That will make an " assign " window.onload => function() . And window.onload will be assign to last function .

But in jQuery,
You can handle event in many times and the browser will make all

```
$("body").on("click",function(){
console.log("make a callback function 1");
});
$("body").on("click",function(){
console.log("make a callback function 2");
});
```

Because jQuery make a callback not "assign".
Hope it helps you.